# how python http request and response works

Tags: python, http

I'm newbie for python, I'm having task so I need to scan wifi and send the data to the server, the below is the format which i have to send, this work fine when enter manually in browser url text box,

```
http://223.56.124.58:8080/ppod-web/ProcessRawData?data={"userId":"2220081127-14","timestamp":"2010-04-12 10:54:24","wifi":{"ssid":"guest","rssi":"80"}}
```

here is my code:

```
import httplib  
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode('{\"userId\":\"20081127-14\",\"timestamp\":\"2010-04-12 10:54:24\",\"wifi\":{\"ssid\":\"guest\",\"rssi\":\"80\"}}')

headers = {"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("http://223.56.124.58:8080")
conn.request("POST","ppod-web/ProcessRawData?data=",params,headers)
response = conn.getresponse()   
print response.status  
print "-----"  
print response.reason  
data = response.read()   
print data
conn.close()
```

thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please use the 'New question' button. :) Original question link: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f7804379-ffed-4ccb-bf96-b60865617396/view-source

Comment: Seconded. Rolled back the edit.

Comment: I need some help on response  generation for make my response only once during the life time of class load

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely, the issue **with the script you posted in the question** is you cannot directly do:

```
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection("http://223.56.124.58:8080/wireless")
```

The exception is triggered in [`getaddrinfo()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo), which calls the C function [`getaddrinfo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) which returns `EAI_NONAME`:

> The node or service is not known; or both node and service are NULL; or AI_NUMERICSERV was specified in hints.ai_flags and service was not a numeric port-number string."

There obviously is a problem with the parameters passed to `getaddrinfo`, and most likely you are trying to get information for the `"223.56.124.58:8080/wireless"` host. Ooops!

Indeed, you cannot directly connect to an URL address. [As the documentation clearly states and shows](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection), you connect to the *server*:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("223.56.124.58", 8080)
```

Then you can do:

```
conn.request("POST", "wireless", params, headers)
```

---

What about **the script you are *actually* using**?

```
conn.request("POST","http://202.45.139.58:8080/ppod-web",params,headers)
```

Even if the connection was correctly formed, that would have you POSTing to `http://202.45.139.58:8080/http://202.45.139.58:8080/ppod-web`. What you really want probably is:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("202.45.139.58", 8080)
conn.request("POST", "ppod-web", params, headers)
```

The error is shown for this line because most likely `HTTPConnection` is a lazy object and only attempts to actually connect to the server when you call `request()`.

---

After you're done fixing the above, you'll need to fix `params`.

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({"wifi":{"ssid":"guest","rssi","80"}})
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> urllib.urlencode({"wifi":{"ssid":"guest","rssi":"80"}})
'wifi=%7B%27rssi%27%3A+%2780%27%2C+%27ssid%27%3A+%27guest%27%7D'
```

To get what you <s>think you</s> want to get, you should do:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({"data": {"wifi":{"ssid":"guest","rssi":"80"}}})
'data=%7B%27wifi%27%3A+%7B%27rssi%27%3A+%2780%27%2C+%27ssid%27%3A+%27guest%27%7D%7D'
```

Comment: hi bro, i'm having 1 prob, when i use hard-coded method data can send to the server, but when i use not hard-coded method i'm gettind error as 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 71, in <module>
    request.add_data(urllib.urlencode(query_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1254, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

can u help me for this, i change the code for reference as above

thanks

Comment: I need some help on response  generation for make my response only once during the life time of class load

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("http://223.56.124.58:8080/wireless")
conn.request("POST", "data", params, headers)
```

try:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("223.56.124.58", port=8080)
conn.request("POST", "/wireless", params, headers)
```

Not sure if it will resolve all your problems, but at least your code will conform to the method/constructor signatures.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback doesn't come from the same code you pasted.

On the error traceback there's a line:

```
conn.request("POST","http://202.45.139.58:8080/ppod-web",params,headers)
```

It is the line 9 of `http.py` however it is not on the code you pasted.

Please paste the actual code.

Comment: sorry nosklo, actually i'm testing with sample codes, mistakenl i paste from different, i've edited the code,can u help me for the http post for different parameter as above format 

,thanks