# Why can't get Response in Python?

Tags: python, http

I'm read the example http.client in python.org

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
data1 = r1.read()  # This will return entire content.
# The following example demonstrates reading data in chunks.
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
```

It's Ok but the following code isn't:

```
 import http.client
 conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.python.org")
 conn.request("GET", "/")
 r1 = conn.getresponse()
 # The different here
 conn.request("GET", "/")
 r1 = conn.getresponse()
Error: http.client.ResponseNotReady: Request-sent
```

I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python official documentation:

> HTTPConnection.getresponse()   Should be called after a request is
>   sent to get the response from the server. Returns an HTTPResponse
>   instance.
>
> **Note: that you must have read the whole response before you can send a new request to the server.**

[**Source**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.getresponse)

As you can notice from note  you must read the whole response before sending request, that's make all difference...

You can take a look on use full links below to get more info about `httplib`:

- [HTTP protocol client](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#module-httplib)
- [how python http request and response works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620228/how-python-http-request-and-response-works)
- [Interact with the Web Using Python and the HTTP Library](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/using-python-httplib)

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what you removed:

```
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
data1 = r1.read()
```

The `print` is harmless, but reading the contents of the response is required before you can get another response on the same connection. Otherwise the response would be held up, blocking further communication.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much